# Typecasting from integer to double

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Below is the basic piece of code that I am trying to run

```
double h_a[9],h_b[2500],h_c[2704];
int r_a,c_a,r_b,c_b,r_c,c_c;
r_a = c_a = 3;
r_b = c_b = 50;
r_c = r_a + r_b - 1;
c_c = c_a + c_b - 1;
for(int i=0;i<(r_a*c_a);i++)
    h_a = double(rand() % 50 + 1);
for(i=0;i<(r_b*c_b);i++)
    h_b = rand() % 50 + 1;
```

It is showing me the following errors:
1. incompatible types in assignment of 'double' to 'double [9]
2. name lookup of 'i' changed for ISO 'for' scoping [-fpermissive]|
3. incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'double [2500]'

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: you just cannot assign a `double` to a `double*`, and `int` to a `double*`....and `i` is not declared in the second `for` statement. you should learn first the basic syntax and rules...

Comment: h_a is an array and you're trying to assign a double value to it.
probably should be h_a[i] = double(rand() % 50 + 1)

Answer (score 1):

`h_a` and `h_b` are arrays. You can't assign a value to an array, only to an element of an array.

Replacing

```
h_a = double(rand() % 50 + 1);
```

by

```
h_a[0] = double(rand() % 50 + 1);
```

and making a similar change in the assignment to `h_b` would satisfy the compiler. I have no idea whether it would be correct.

You have two `for` loops. The first defines the loop variable in the loop header; the second does not:

```
for (int i = blah; blah; blah) { ... }
for (i = blah; blah; blah) { ... }
```

The scope of the `i` defined in the first loop is just the loop. It's not visible in the second loop. But in an old version of C++, the scope extended to the block enclosing the loop. Under those rules, it would have been legal. Apparently the compiler still recognizes the old rules. Change `i = ...` in the second loop to `int i = ...`. You'll then have two distinct variables, both named `i`, one for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an array's name with a value, which is wrong. You can assign it to an element of the array.
i is declared in first for loop. That's why it is not visible in second for loop. declare it before first loop starts.